# Can I connect directly via ethernet?

Tags: networking, ethernet-port

At the moment, I am SSHing into my Pi from my laptop. Both are connected to my router. However, it's a bit of a bother connecting the Pi to the router (ie router on the other side of the house).

Can I connect my Pi to the laptop with an Ethernet cable from the laptop directly to the Pi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Pi's NIC supports Auto-MDIX, so you should be able to connect it to the laptop using a standard Ethernet cable.

Comment: Do you know how I can then connect to the Pi? It comes up as an 'unidentified network'. I tried putting the `Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address` into putty, but no luck.

Comment: Any ideas? I'm stumped

Comment: You could use a static IP-address configuration on both computers, e.g. set one to 192.168.0.1 and the other to 192.168.0.2 with a netmask of 255.255.255.0

Comment: You could also install avahi-daemon on the Pi and use link-local networking.