# Connect Pi to Laptop

Tags: pi-3

I have a Laptop, a Pi, with raspbian already installed on the SD card. SSH and WiFi are not enabled on th Pi. I have not internet and I have not any Router. How can I connect the Laptop to the Pi?
Many thanks

Comment: Does  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/3625/64792 answer your question?

Comment: That still requires SSH (or similar).

Comment: @Lahcene f you lost your login credentials *["I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)* may help.

Comment: Also: **If you cannot access the first partition from your windows laptop,** it is because either **1)** Your laptop does not have an SD card slot, in which case you can get a USB adaptor for <= ~ $10 USD **2)** The SD card is not properly formatted or is physically defective/damaged, so will not work in the Pi or anything else.  You need to create the card properly, or get a new undamaged card and start again.

Comment: **3)** There is something wrong with your laptop, in which case you should pursue this on a Windows forum somewhere and tell them, *"I have an MBR formatted SD card with a VFAT/FAT32 partition at the beginning, but strangely my Windows laptop does not see it! What do I do?"*  -> Hopefully that will reaffirm that the reason is one of the three already given.  There are no other choices unless you can *provide concrete evidence that none of them are true in this case.*  You will not be able to do that, but in trying to do so you may well find the actual cause of your problems.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

1. Try using an ethernet cable; you will probably have to do some configuration on the laptop. Configuring networking on your laptop is off-topic here, but you should be able to enable a DHCP server which is the best option. The Pi should then connect automatically. *Unfortunately*, actually logging in still requires SSH (and there isn't anything you can do without logging in).  But this easy to enable even if you do not want wifi (just leave an empty `ssh` file in the first partition of the SD card).
2. There is a serial console enabled by default.  To use that, you will need a 3.3V USB to TTL serial (this has four or five wire leads that connect to GPIOs on the Pi, not the other common kind of USB serial cable, which has a 9 pin RS232 connector).  There are many many explanations of the necessary details here and elsewhere online -- all you really have to do is make sure the wires are on the right GPIOs, and find some appropriate software on the laptop to use it.

Comment: My laptop is running Windows. I can't access the SD card to write in the ssh file.
Many thanks.

Comment: The first partition is formatted `vfat` and can be accessed from any operating system.  The part you can't see on Window is the much bigger second partition.  This is why the methodology with the `ssh` file is the way it is (and I think you can add a `wpa_supplicant.conf` too).  *Anyone* with a computer with an SD card reader can do it.

Answer (score 0):

As goldilocks said you can enable ssh by adding a file to the boot partition of the SD Card.

You can then ssh from most systems using an Ethernet cable with ssh pi@raspberrpypi.local

You can then configure the Pi, although it is much easier with a screen and keyboard.